# Defining an operator for the let statement (binding)

Tags: f#, metaprogramming

In F#, is it possible to define an operator, say (<<), that would assign a value to a variable like so :

```
let (<<) var value = ??<let var = value>??
```

that would compile inside the program and for which the resulting variable **var** of the *let* assignment could be used later in the program.

If it is possible, what is the syntax between the `??` delimiters ?

If not, what is the reason that would enlighten my knowledge of F# ?

**Notes** :

I suppose I cannot use *Code Quotations* in this case.

As a *let binding*, it is not a complete expression ; unlike other examples of operator definition (eg. (+)) I have seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if you deal with **variables**, not bindings.

For example for ref cells you can do this:

```
let a = ref 5

let (<<) var value = var := value

a << 6

!a // returns 6
```

You are basically aliasing the `(:=)` operator.

For let bindings it's not possible, because they are immutable and `let` is more a keyword than a first-class function.

Comment: Thanks @Gustavo. If i pass a string "var" instead, would it be possible to instantiate it ? let (<<) "var" value.

Comment: That's a different story. You will be mutating a variable based on the name, but the name may be lost at runtime. It might be possible using reflection and quotations.

Comment: I have accepted your answer in the case on ref. But I am afraid it is not easy with quotations. From msdn : "For a let binding, for example, you need both the definition of the bound name and an additional expression that uses the binding. In verbose syntax, this is an expression that follows the in keyword. At the top-level in a module, this is just the next expression in the module, but in a quotation, it is explicitly required."

Comment: I agree, that's not easy. And you will loose type safety, since the compiler will no longer know to which variable are you assigning, so will not know against which type to check.

Comment: Gustavo,an interesting initiative is Yaaf.FSharp.Scripting on github which can make possible let assignment with the following syntax : fsiSession.Let "test" 25. Have you heard of it ?

Comment: Thanks @FZed I didn't know about that project. The first example seems to be exactly what you're looking for.